# Is it possible to retrieve the username and password in one page to another page in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a login control where user enters the username and passwords.I want to retrieve those values of username and password  into another page in the application? Is there a way to do that in C#.I am using asp.net login control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the password, as that's double-blind to protect the user's security.  But the username is easy to get:

I use this frequently:

```
lblUser.Text = "Welcome " + User.Identity.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is call [`Membership.GetUser();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcxcb339.aspx#Y0)

Answer (score 0):

How about `HttpContext.Current.User`?

Answer (score -1):

Excuse my intrusion as I don't know either C# or asp.net. However, you could have a public variable on the system which could hold those info across pages.

Comment: Sorry - have to downvote.  ASP.NET already supports several constructs which are intended to maintain current-user-specific information across multiple page requests (usually, throughout the lifespan of the user's session).  Your answer is vague ("the system"), and even misleading (assuming the possibility of multiple concurrent users, you certainly wouldn't want to store one user's name in a system-wide variable).

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot more polite of you to just point out those things  ("several constructs" -- no; not asking for a class in ASP.NET) then be arrogant to downvote? It costs points and, if you can read English, I start with "Excuse ..." so, I had no intentions to mislead.

Comment: I'm not downvoting to be arrogant or impolite.  I'm downvoting to encourage readers to disregard your response, as it doesn't solve the original question and could lead to more problems should someone attempt to follow it.  (Typing "Excuse..." doesn't make your answer any more useful or correct.)  I don't enumerate the other constructs, as they have already been detailed by other responders.